# How to add request headers to window.open in javascript?

Tags: javascript, c#

In my application I need to open a **pdf** in a new window. I'm making a `window.open` call for that. Mine is an **MVC** application. The *url* for the `window.open` contains my controller name and action method so that it will hit the respective action method.

But due to some reason, when I run with `http` request, I'm able to open the `pdf`, which means my controller call returns `200`. But in the case of `https`, my controller throws a `302`. Is there any solution for this?

One more thing which I found out is, when I compose the https request in Fiddler by adding some request headers to it, my controller returns 200. But I'm not able to add the request headers in window.open. Is there any way to do this?

I cannot go for a server side coding here. I have to complete it in the js itself.

Comment: I guess for https calls your calling domain should also be https

Comment: @VinodLouis Yes, both are https. I'm making my code run in https domain.

Comment: does the called url https has a valid pdf on that url ?

Comment: @VinodLouis Yes, it has a valid pdf.